# What is an equivalent of *Nix 'cut' command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, split, powershell-2.0

I have following content in a configuration file (sample.cfg),

```
Time_Zone_Variance(Mins):300
Alert_Interval(Mins):2
Server:10.0.0.9
Port:1840
```

I'm trying to store an each values after the `:` by using `split` in PowerShell. but i'm not able to produce require output.

Can someone tell me how to use PowerShell  `split` for the above problem ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can read the contents of the file using `Get-Content`, then pipe each line through `ForEach-Object`, then use the split command on each line, taking the second item in the array as follows:

```
$filename = "sample.cfg"

Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object {
    $_.split(":")[1]
}
```

**Output**

```
300
2
10.0.0.9
1840
```

**Update**

I prefer the approach by @AnsgarWiechers, but if you *really* need specifically named values you could create a hashtable and replace the name with the value:

```
$configValues = @{
    hour    = "Time_Zone_Variance(Mins)"
    min     = "Alert_Interval(Mins)"
    server  = "Server"
    port    = "Port"
}

Get-Content $filename | ForEach-Object {

    # Courtesy of Ansgar Wiechers
    $key, $value = $_ -split ':', 2

    foreach($configValuesKey in $($configValues.keys)) {
        if ($configValues[$configValuesKey] -eq $key)
        {
            $configValues[$configValuesKey] = $value
        }
    }
}

write-host "`nAll Values:"
$configValues
write-host "`nIndividual value:"
$configValues.port
```

**Output**

```
All Values:

Name                           Value                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                             
port                           1840                                                                                              
min                            2                                                                                                 
server                         10.0.0.9                                                                                          
hour                           300                                                                                               

Individual value:
1840
```

Comment: David thanks, Can you tell me how to store each value in a variable like `$hour = 300, $min = 2, $server = 10.0.0.9, $port = 1840`

Comment: For individually named variables you could do something like `$configValues.Keys | % { New-Variable -Name $_ -Value $configValues[$_] }`.

Comment: great answers here.  if you happen to be splitting on space instead of colon, and your data may have a variable number of spaces as a single delimiter, don't forget to collapse them via something like `($_ -replace '  *', ' ')`.

Answer (score 17):

How's this?

```
function cut {
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)] [string]$inputobject,
    [string]$delimiter='\s+',
    [string[]]$field
  )

  process {
    if ($field -eq $null) { $inputobject -split $delimiter } else {
      ($inputobject -split $delimiter)[$field] }
  }
}


PS C:\> 'hi:there' | cut -f 0 -d :
hi

PS C:\> 'hi:there' | cut -f 1 -d :
there

PS C:\> 'hi:there' | cut -f 0,1 -d :
hi
there

PS C:\> 'hi:::there' | cut -f 0 -d :+
hi

PS C:\> 'hi   there' | cut
hi
there
```

Comment: It is close to 'cut' - only new line characters should not be inserted.  Input is one line, output is as many lines as number of fields you selected.  +1 anyway.

Comment: The output is actually an array, but powershell displays it that way.

Answer (score 8):

For a more succint syntax, this will also do the trick:

```bsh
((Get-Content "your-file.txt") -Split ":")[1]
```

So the trick to use the `-Split` method is to have a `String` object returned by `Get-Content` (alias `cat` can also be used, actually), and from the resulting `String[]` object you can use the brackets to extract the `n`<sup>th</sup> item.

> **Note:** Using `-Split` without parenthesis around `Get-Content` won't work since `-Split` is not a parameter name for that command... ‍♂️

Comment: I converted the output of ns-lookup to a string but that does not work : `(nslookup X.Y.Z.T | Out-String).Split(' ')[-1]`

Comment: I tried this : `(nslookup 172.16.78.12)[-3..-2] > your-file.txt` and then I type your command but it only processed the first line.

Comment: This answer is wrong because it works only for a single line. Please stop upvoting it!

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you don't want to just split the lines, but actually create key/value pairs. That could be achieved like this:

```
$config = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\sample.cfg' | % {
  $key, $value = $_ -split ':', 2
  $config[$key] = $value
}
```

You could also use the [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx) cmdlet:

```
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\sample.cfg' | % {
  ConvertFrom-StringData ($_ -replace ':','=')
}
```

The `-replace` operation is necessary, because `ConvertFrom-StringData` expects key and value to be separated by `=`. If you could change the delimiter in the config file from `:` to `=`, you could use `ConvertFrom-StringData $_` without replacement.