# in git ls-remote How can i get the branch names only without the commit IDs

Tags: git

i do
git ls-remote and i get the remote branches and the commit IDs. 
is there away to get the branch names without the commit IDs.?
this is what i do :

```
git ls-remote --heads
```

and im getting this result:

```
038700e8xxxxxxc96bb78adc6d22287370        refs/heads/release/ddddd.3
d9ebd03axxxxx212fdf63f22b092aaff6c6f0e    refs/heads/release/ddddd.4
63a9be2d6a77414c65189ea0ef76d65a23a3e910  refs/heads/release/ddddd.4
db6cf449xxxxxx15cbf711745f94875ed18bd     refs/heads/release/ddddd.5
49ba61331ebaca7aexxxxxxf2e9dfc9b5591      refs/heads/release/ddddd.6
acc32db7f25d2b3e616613a389c93eae82d46323  refs/heads/release/ddddd.7
```

not using linux tools , as im using windows also can't rely
 on awk and friends

Comment: Can you explain what you try to achieve please? You mention "checkout a single file" in the comments, but listing branches is unrelated with file checkout.

Answer (score 2):

Could do

```
git ls-remote --heads | cut -f 2
```

Comment: 'not using linux tools, as im using windows also can't rely on awk and friends'
Your answer contains cut.

Comment: If you don't need to be cross-platform, you can try a PowerShell equivalent of "cut":
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634022/what-is-an-equivalent-of-nix-cut-command-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-remote --heads origin | awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: 'not using linux tools, as im using windows also can't rely on awk and friends'
Your answer contains awk.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the remote branches with:

```
git branch --remote
```

Is it what you are after?

Comment: im using this method to checkout single file so ( i don't know why really ) 
it doesn't work 
like in this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository

Comment: It will not list remote branches that are not fetched to your local repo. `git ls-remote` will connect to the remote and list all of the missing branches.